# Редирект на view('welcome'), если запрос http в laravel

Tags: ajax, request, laravel7

Друзья, такой вопрос. Я использую reactJs на frontend и laravel на beckend. Стоит задача разграничения ajax и http запросов. Вот этот код решает задачу (метод контроллера):

```
   public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $snippet = Snippet::all();
        return Response()->json($snippet);
    } else {
        return view('welcome');
    }

}
```

но мне хочется более красивый вариант с точки зрения архитектуры, т.к. не комильфо писать в каждом экшене контроллера
условные конструкции. Хотелось бы один раз проверить что $request это http и перенаправить пользователя на view('welcome'). Искал решение чтобы выполнить такую проверку в файле routes/web.php перед объявлением всех роутов, но ничего не получилось. Если не перенаправлять пользователя на 'welcome', где находятся входные скрипты reactJs, то пользователь получает голый json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве решения Вашей проблемы предлагаю использовать `middleware`. Но подключать шаблон если не корректный запрос, не совсем верно, нужно делать именно редирект (который Вы так и называете). Создайте страницу ошибки или страницу `welcome` и делайте редирект туда. Например:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRequest
{
    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('welcome');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Далее регистрируете данный `middleware` в конфиге и делаете так:

```
Route::middleware('check.request')->group(function () {
    //Все запросы которые должны выполняться по ajax
});
```

**UPD** если Вы пытаетесь достичь SPA приложения, то все запросы должен обрабатывать один контроллер который возвращает Вашу `welcome` страницу.
Маршрут должен быть таким:

```
Route::get('/{any?}', 'MyController@index')->where('any','.*');
```

Все запросы идут на 1 контроллер и далее в нем делаете так:

```
...index(Request $request) {
    return view('welcome');
}
```

И далее у вас должен Быть подключен router который уже смотрит на url и подключает тот компонент который соответствует шаблону!
и там в методе `componentDidMount` Вы грузите Ваши ajax. В результате проверки на бэке не нужны!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но неуверен, что вы правильно меня поняли, хотя в laravel я совсем зеленый, делаю первые шаги. Запросы http на самом деле корректные и страница ошибок здесь не нужна. Просто, когда пользователь обновляет страницу вручную (прямой http запрос), необходимо чтобы этот запрос прошел через reactJs, для чего и делается перенаправление на view welcome? Т.к. у меня на фронте react то и все запросы у меня пока что ajax.

Comment: @AndreyOv делается это так. У вас должен быть настроен  `react-router` далее перемещаясь по страницам вы попадаете в тот или иной компонент. В котором с помощью ajax  грузите данные для страницы. Когда пользователь обновляет страницу, Вы должны оставаться в том же компоненте и в методе componentDidMount грузите данные по ajax. А если как Вы говорите у Вас за место html голый json приходит, значит не корректно настроена маршрутизация. Так как если Вы хотите сделать SPA приложение, то роут должен быть другой (приведу пример в ответе). Прочитайте как оно организуется в сети.тут целая лекция нужна

Comment: @AndreyOv дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Сделаю еще уточнение. У меня корректно настроен BrowserRouter в React и маршрутизация проходит нормально. Т.е. реакт рисует все отлично если движение начинается с маршрута Route::get('/', function(){ return view('welcome')}) и если я прохожу по ссылке /snippets c главной страницы то все ОК (потому что используется ajax и browserhistory) но если я в адресной строке введу /snippets то мне идет голый json, если я не выполню в контроллере проверку и не подключу шаблон welcome. Просто я хочу выполнить эту проверку не в контроллере у каждого метода, а до того как начнется перебор маршрутов

Comment: @AndreyOv я Вам привел выше пример маршрута который должен обрабатывать http запросы, когда всё приложение на ajax. Если что загуглите SPA LARAVEL там подробно будет. Все остальные запросы лучше писать в api.php иначе не будут отрабатывать get запросы

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за наводку, SPA LARAVEL!

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, все получилось! Наводка SPA LARAVEL полностью помогла решить вопрос. Итак, как вы и написали выше все http запросы идут на web.php где находится один единственный роут: Route::get('/{any?}', 'MyController@index')->where('any','.*'); Контроллер содержит единственный метод index в котором делается return view('welcome'), Все остальные роуты которые генерируются ajax-ом кладутся в файл routes/api.php и ко всем ajax запросам добавляется prefix /api. Т.е. если раньше я писал axios.get('/snippets'), то теперь нужно писать axios.get('/api/snippets'). Всё супер!

Comment: @AndreyOv рад помочь)